# how to update a field if user follows a record

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

My use case is to find total followers on a particular record

So when somebody follows/unfollows that record i would like to update the number of followers of that particular record .stored as a custom field on the object

Possible solution i could think of is
 have a trigger on entity subscription object ?if so where do we write it?so an after insert/before delete trigger should help in updating?

Or can i avoid code at all?

Comment: You cannot write trigger on EntitySubscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object involved in this process is an `EntitySubscription`. It is the junction between the follower and the object - whether that's another user or a record.

Unfortunately, this object does not support triggers.

If it isn't critical to store this information and it would suffice to just display it on screen, you could implement an inline VF page which uses [Recipe #3](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes) to retrieve the count for the current record.

<strike>This object is not available as a workflow target so you will need to implement it with a trigger on the `EntitySubscription` object. The trigger should handle `after insert`, `after update`, `before delete` and `after undelete`</strike>

[Here is a chatter recipe link (Recipe #3)](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes) which provides a basic query to retrieve the number of followers for a single record. To be used in a trigger, this will need to be altered to handle the worst case scenario of 200 different `parentid` values at once and update all of those parents with the aggregate result of the number of followers.

If it was an object that supported a trigger, the code would look similar to this:

```
public class EntitySubscriptionTriggerHelper {
    public static void CalculateNumberOfSubscribers(Map<Id, EntitySubscription> triggerMap) {

        List<Id> entityParentIds = new List<Id>();
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for (EntitySubscription subscription : triggerMap.values()) {
            entityParentIds.add(subscription.ParentId);
        }

        // use an aggregate query to calculate the total number of followers
        List<AggregateResult> aggregateResults = [SELECT parentId
                                                        , COUNT(id) subscriberCount 
                                                    FROM EntitySubscription 
                                                    WHERE ParentId IN :entityParentIds
                                                    GROUP BY ParentId];

        for (AggregateResult ar : aggregateResults) {
            accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(Id = String.valueOf(ar.get('parentId'))
                                            , numberOfFollowers__c = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('subscriberCount'))));
        }                            

        if (!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update accountsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we write a trigger on entity subscription object?as per my understanding you cannot?..my usecase when user follows a record,update a custom field(which acts like a counter of followers)

Comment: Nope. You sure can't - that's not a standard object which supports triggers. Sorry about that, my answer is totally invalid.