# Follow multiple objects on Chatter when following one object

Tags: trigger, chatter, entitysubscription

We have a custom field on the `Opportunity` object which creates a parent/child lookup relationship. A parent opportunity may have multiple child opportunities. A family of opportunities is simply a group of opportunity objects related directly or transitively through that field. A child has a parent, and through that parent has siblings.

The next step is if a user follows one opportunity, the system will automatically create `EntitySubscriptions` so the user will follow the entire family of opportunities.

It is not possible to [create a trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22119/how-to-update-a-field-if-user-follows-a-record) on the `EntitySubscription` SObject: this would be the easiest solution, as an `after insert` trigger would make it trivial to look up the family of opportunities, find missing `EntitySubscriptions`, and create them. I did not see any [Chatter code recipes](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes) that might help. Finally, the GUI functionality to follow an object is not even a button, it is a hyperlink outside the editable page layout.

How can I implement this functionality given the constraints of the Salesforce platform?

Comment: While less than ideal from a usability standpoint, I wound up creating a custom button on the `Opportunity` page layout to do this. I do not like this approach because now there are two ways to subscribe to Chatter on the same page and one of them is the wrong way, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently don't have a built-in way to do this. However you can create a VisualForce page to follow the child opportunities when the parent is followed. Please let me know if you have additional questions.